LookUpTables in Rust
In typescript I can fetch a lookup table account as so :
const lookupTableAccount = (
  await connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress)
).value;

then I can use it in my V0 message
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: keypair.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash,
  instructions: [gas1, gas2 , Ixn ],
}).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount!]);


Is there an equivalent in Rust ? I have searched for hours and surprisingly found nothing for such an important feature

You can use a pretty similar function called solana_program::message::v0::Message::try_compile, ie:
    let raw_account = client.get_account(&address_lookup_table_key)?;
    let address_lookup_table = AddressLookupTable::deserialize(&raw_account.data)?;
    let address_lookup_table_account = AddressLookupTableAccount {
        key: address_lookup_table_key,
        addresses: address_lookup_table.addresses.to_vec(),
    };

    let blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash()?;
    let tx = VersionedTransaction::try_new(
        VersionedMessage::V0(v0::Message::try_compile(
            &payer.pubkey(),
            &[instruction],
            &[address_lookup_table_account],
            blockhash,
        )?),
        &[payer],
    )?;

Copied from the example at https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/message/v0/struct.Message.html#method.try_compile
